# TypeError: create_bool(): incompatible function arguments

Tags: python, mediapipe

I made a code detector that can detect hand, face, pose, etc. But when I run this in Visual Studio, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: create_bool(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: bool) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet

Invoked with: 0.5
```

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time

class findhand():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, detectionCon=0.5
             ,trackCon=0.5):

        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands

        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands
                                        ,self.detectionCon
                                        ,self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms,
                                               self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)

        return img

class findFace():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxFaces=1, detectionCon=0.5
               ,trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxFaces = maxFaces
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon
        self.mpFaceMesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh

        self.face_mesh = self.mpFaceMesh.FaceMesh(self.mode
                                                 ,self.maxFaces
                                                 ,self.detectionCon
                                                 ,self.trackCon)

        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

   def findFace(self, img, draw=True):

        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.face_mesh.process(imgRGB)

        if self.results.multi_face_landmarks:
            for faceLms in self.results.multi_face_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, faceLms,
                                               self.mpFaceMesh.FACE_CONNECTIONS)

        return img

class findPose():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, complexity=1,detectionCon=0.5,landmarks=True
                 ,trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxFace = 1
        self.detectionCon = 0.5
        self.trackCon = 0.5
        self.landmarks = landmarks
        self.complexity = complexity
        self.mpPose = mp.solutions.pose

        self.pose = self.mpPose.Pose(self.mode, self.complexity
                                         ,self.detectionCon
                                         ,self.trackCon
                                         ,self.landmarks)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    def findPose(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.pose.process(imgRGB)

        if self.result.pose_landmarks:
            PoseLms = self.results.pose_landmarks
            mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, PoseLms, self.mpPose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                                  drawSpec, drawSpec)

        return img

def main():

    cTime, pTime = 0, 0

    hand_detector = findhand()
    face_detector = findFace()
    pose_detector = findPose()

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

    while True:

        success, img = cap.read()
        img = face_detector.findFace(img)
        if not success:
            print("GPU Didn't Success At Loading Video")
            continue

        handlmList = hand_detector.findHands(img)

        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime

        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.imshow("Detector", img)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) != -1:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The full error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\tmdgh\Desktop\DetectionModule2.py", line 135, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\tmdgh\Desktop\DetectionModule2.py", line 107, in main
    pose_detector = findPose()
  File "c:\Users\tmdgh\Desktop\DetectionModule2.py", line 76, in __init__
    self.pose = self.mpPose.Pose(self.mode 
  File "C:\Users\tmdgh\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\pose.py", line 146, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\tmdgh\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 258, in __init__
    self._input_side_packets = {
  File "C:\Users\tmdgh\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 259, in <dictcomp>
    name: self._make_packet(self._side_input_type_info[name], data)
  File "C:\Users\tmdgh\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 513, in _make_packet
    return getattr(packet_creator, 'create_' + packet_data_type.value)(data)
TypeError: create_bool(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: bool) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet

Invoked with: 0.5
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by passing the **named (keyword) arguments** instead of positional arguments.

This ensured right argument is being passed at right place.

```
self.mpHands.Hands(
                   static_image_mode=True/False,
                   model_complexity=yourNumber,
                   smooth_landmarks=True/False,
                   enable_segmentation=True/False,
                   smooth_segmentation=True/False,
                   min_detection_confidence=yourConfidence,
                   min_tracking_confidence=yourConfidence):
```

See also: [Why You Should Typically Use Named Arguments in Python | Thomas Stringer](https://trstringer.com/python-named-arguments/)

Comment: Confirmed. Work for me too also in pose detection

Comment: Advantage of _named arguments_ among expressiveness is also robustness in case of changed parameter-order by a new version.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line:

```
self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands ,self.detectionCon ,self.trackCon)
```

With this one:

```
self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.modelComplex, self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
```

Also add parameter of `modelComplex` in `__init__` method, you are getting this error because you are missing one parameter that is model complexity.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, detectionCon=False, trackCon=0.5):
```

Answer (score 1):

just use this one

```
self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands
                                        ,min_detection_confidence = 0.5
                                        ,min_tracking_confidence = 0.5
                                )

self.face_mesh = self.mpFaceMesh.FaceMesh(self.mode,self.maxFaces
                                                 ,min_detection_confidence = 0.5
                                                 ,min_tracking_confidence = 0.5
                                          )

self.pose = self.mpPose.Pose(self.mode, self.complexity
                                       ,min_detection_confidence = 0.5
                                        ,min_tracking_confidence = 0.5
                                         ,self.landmarks
                             )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Pose(SolutionBase) class of MediaPipe, you can see def `__init__`:

```py
class Pose(SolutionBase):
    def __init__(self,
                 static_image_mode=False,
                 model_complexity=1,
                 smooth_landmarks=True,
                 enable_segmentation=False,
                 smooth_segmentation=True,
                 min_detection_confidence=0.5,
                 min_tracking_confidence=0.5):
```

You should have the same parameters in the class findPose() `__init__`. Of course you can name them whatever you want, but the sequence and types must be the same.

More information: https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/pose#model_complexity

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01sAkU_NvOY watch from 1:11

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be related to the version of **mediapipe or opencv** you are using.
Please look out to the appropriate combinaison of version and you should be good